# Picasso is not able to load the Images from FirebaseStorage

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage, picasso

It seems like Picasso is not able to load the Images from FirebaseStorage.

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter, final int i, @NonNull ItemListProduct itemListProduct) {

    Picasso.get().load(itemListProduct.getITEM_IMAGE())
            .error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18).into(firebaseAdapter.itemImage);
```

Here is the other way which I have tried from my end:

```
firebaseAdapter.itemImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Picasso.get().load(itemListProduct.getITEM_IMAGE()))));
```

And this is my Layout:

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:background="#E9E9E9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/ItemImageViewAdapter"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

I have also checked the previous error but still, I didn't get the Answer for this. So, I am posting it again the question of how do I retrieve the Images from FirebaseStorage URL.

Below is my Storage Reference URL:

```
 uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                     downloadImageUrl = reference.toString();
```

Is Picasso doesn't work now???

I have even tried with Glide but still, it doesn't work.

```
Glide.with(context).load(itemListProduct.getITEM_IMAGE()).error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18)
            .into(firebaseAdapter.itemImage);
```

Comment: Have you checked your Firebase Storage access rules?

Comment: where is the holder class , how are you passed adapter in the `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I have passed the Value in ImageView for the Picture. The issue which I have faced is that the link which I have saved as the storage reference link not the downloadable URL. So, I have rectified it and I was able to view it inside the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

In onBindViewHolder

Picasso.get().load("try any static link first")
            .error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18).into(firebaseAdapter.itemImage);

to check where the actual problem is.

Comment: `((StorageReference)reference).mStorageUri` here the reference seen unable to identify the method in firebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: i mean to say have you tried any static link in load method?

Comment: I haven't, let me try it.

Comment: even after using the static link, it didn't work. Still, I get as error pic

Comment: Anyone any method from which I will be able to display the Images from Url of FirebaseStorage????

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the answer to why I was not able to load the Image from the firebase database.

The reference.getPath() is the path location ID, not the Download Url after I have to redirect it to the Download Url I was able to populate the Image in my app. Thank you! Even though no one tries to help me out.